# Janeau wearing direction

Tags: brahman, vedic-rituals, gayatri-mantra, bhavishya-purana, trinity

Does the Janeau or Poonol (Yajnopavitham) for Brahmins wearing direction from left to right is for signifying that they have to be more Justice and Righteous oriented?

Comment: Are you asking in case of Brahmins only or all dvija?

Comment: there are 3 directions, depending on the type of karma being done. on left shoulder - for devas, on right shoulder - for pitrus, on both shoulders - for men

Comment: Yes. I would like to understand the motivation / references as to be worn one way or the other. Like what karma for Rishis, Devas and Pitr. Scriptural references appreciated. All dvija as well